# When a file is "opened with" a winforms application how do I get the application to use that file's directory?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, open-with

I am able to set my `.mdb` files to "open with" my winforms application, but that only opens the winforms application without loading the file. Is there any event that is triggered upon opening the application through a file that will allow me to grab the filename/file-directory to load it into my app?

#### Update:

apparently this can be done for "Windows Store Apps": [File "Open with" my Windows Store App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892461/file-open-with-my-windows-store-app)

But it seems as though my winforms project lacks a `package.appxmanifest` to edit these settings from, nor does my project have access to the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.FileActivatedEventArgs` and `Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.OnFileActivated`
APIs needed for this method.

Comment: It is passed as a commandline argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double-click an mdb file, your application will be executed with mdb file argument. Similar to calling your app from command line:

```
> your-app.exe "test.mdb"
```

You should use the **args** in the **Main** method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // check that user provided a file to open
        if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
        {
            var mdbFilePath = args[0];
            // TODO: read the file
        }

        // ...
```

Comment: This didn't work for whatever reason (`args` was an empty array) but it led me to the alternative method of fetching these args `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]` which did work.

Comment: turns out this only returns the path to the application directory and not the selected file the application was opened from.

Comment: `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]` always returns the app path as the first element. You get the file that was passed as command line if you have setup your App's `ProgId` correctly in the Registry or your App is the `(Default)` associate in the `Shell->Open->Command` of the file's `ProgId`. In the form of `"The Full path of your app" %1`

Comment: Of course, any command line argument is stored in `args[0]`, `args[1]` etc. and `.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]`, `.GetCommandLineArgs()[2]` etc.

Comment: @Murat NVM this is the correct solution, `args` returns an empty array when it's run via the executable directly which led me to believe that it wasn't working at all when I was testing it in Visual Studio (since I assumed it would give me the directory regardless of where the application was opened from).  I later found out with further testing that it does in fact contain the filename in `args[0]` when I open a file with the application.